# Relation between columns and rows in $n\times m$ matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

How can I prove this argument?

> If $A$ is a $n\times m$ matrix, the column sums of $A$ are zero, then the rows of $A$ are linearly dependent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all the column sums are $0$, that means that the sum of all the rows is the $0$ vector (since each component in the sum of all rows is a column sum). This is a concrete, non-trivial linear dependence, so the rows are linearly dependent.

By request: If $A_{ij}$ is entry $(i,j)$ of the matrix $A$, $A_{\bullet i}$ is the $i$th column and $A_{i\bullet}$ the $i$th row, then we are given that for any $j$,
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n A_{ij}=0
$$
This implies that
$$
\sum_{i=1}^n A_{i\bullet}=\vec 0
$$
because all the components are $0$ by the sum above. This is a linear combination with non-zero coefficients that gives zero. That's the definition of linear dependence.

Comment: can you write it by symbols

Comment: Sure. I don't think it makes the answer any better, but it's easy enough.